# localize devextreme dx-date-box Angular 2+ in custom language

Tags: devextreme-angular

I would to like localize `devextreme` `dx-date-box` in **Armenian** language, I'm working with `devextreme-intl` , I added for the devextreme grid my custom language `.json` file into `devextreme/localization/messages` but for `dx-date-box` I can't, could you help me how can I do it?

And please when you install node-modules, after installation change the `module.exports = require("stream")`; into `module.exports = require("readable-stream")`; the file url is `node_modules/jszip/lib/readable-stream-browser.js`
[localizate-dx-date-box.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/06cyp9rp5laxjjp/localizate-dx-date-box.zip?dl=0)

I've posted into the [Github](https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-angular/issues/914) this question.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've solved the localization with **custom language** in my case in **[Armenian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armenia)** for whole [devextreme](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/Overview/Angular/Light/) components (including calendar `dx-date-box`) but with [Globalize](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Localization/UsingGlobalize/Angular/Light/) not with [Intl](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Localization/UsingIntl/Angular/Light/), I've changed the location of the JSON files move it into `assets/i18n` and into the JSON files I've added the calendar's translating, so you need only download the project and install,  `npm install`, I've done some changing into the configuration.

The project `Angular CLI: 7.0.7` [globalize-localization.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dotasf7u7ozaxt3/globalize-localization.zip?dl=0)

> Add "typings.d.ts" file into the project [see here](https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-angular/blob/master/docs/setup-3rd-party-dependencies.md#globalize-registration)

```
src/typings.d.ts
```

> package.json

I've added `"typings": "typings.d.ts"`

> tsconfig.json

add `"path"` like this [github.com/DevExpress](https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-angular/blob/master/docs/setup-3rd-party-dependencies.md#globalize-registration), some modules (`"resolveJsonModule": true, "esModuleInterop": true`) for using JSON files into the project.

The question is posted in the Devextreme Support Center
[devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T698989/how-to-localize-datebox-to-a-custom-language-in-angular)

[image]